# Docker alpine does nothing on command inside shell

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux, ts-node

I have the following docker declaration for Alpine based node application.

```
FROM node:8-alpine

RUN npm install typescript
RUN npm install ts-node
RUN npm install puppeteer

CMD [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

Inside it I'm trying to launch puppeteer to render some page. I'm mounting external ts file just to execute it like this:

```
docker run -v "$(pwd):/test/" --net host -it test-chromium
```

And when I'm trying to execute inside this command

```
npx ts-node /test/render.ts
```

It's just showing that ts-node was installed and hangs after it. Nothing is happening. To check if this is chromium run specific issue I tried execute just ts-node in REPL mode like so:

```
npx ts-node
```

and directly through ./bin

```
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node
```

Nothing happen. After Enter hit console just hangs and no input prompt is shown. Even after modification of docker to execute this directly from declaration nothing changes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could it be a problem in `/test/render.ts` ?

Comment: @Leo, thanks, I found the issue. Left the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. It's ts-node which hangs without `tsconfig.json`. Without it, as I was tried to run it from root, typescript tying to traverse all the folders for files to be compiled. After `tsconfig.ts` was added and appropriate limits was set, script started execution.

Some comments on this issue from github:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/690#issuecomment-424178198